# Remove thumb text from rangeseekbar

Tags: android, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I have one range seekbar as per below image

[image]

I use below code for range seekbar integration:

https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar

My issue is I want to remove Value of seekbar **275** and **1064** when I scroll it and also remove Min and Max label so is it possible on that? You all suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya  : Where i found layout.addView(rangeSeekBar);?

Answer (score 4):

Use compile:

```
'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
```

And add in your layout :

```
<org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" app:showLabels="false" app:valuesAboveThumbs="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines 462 and 463 from this file "https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar/blob/master/rangeseekbar/src/main/java/com/yahoo/mobile/client/android/util/rangeseekbar/RangeSeekBar.java#L462" in your library.

Answer (score -1):

All those texts are drawn in the `onDraw()` method of `RangeSeekbar`. You should look at the code in `onDraw()`, find the lines:

```
canvas.drawText()
```

then remove or modify it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Put this in your Gradle:

```
compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
```

And this in Your Xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/seekbar_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And add this code in your Activity:

```
 RangeSeekBar<Integer> rangeSeekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(this);
 // Set the range
 rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(15, 90);
 rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(20);
 rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(88);

 // Add to layout
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.seekbar_placeholder);
 layout.addView(rangeSeekBar);
```

Answer (score -2):

On the RangeSeekBar java file, remove:

```
canvas.drawText(minLabel, 0, minMaxHeight, paint);
canvas.drawText(maxLabel, getWidth() - minMaxLabelSize, minMaxHeight, paint);
```

for the min and max labels

and remove

```
if (!selectedValuesAreDefault) {
        paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // give text a bit more space here so it doesn't get cut off
        int offset = PixelUtil.dpToPx(getContext(), TEXT_LATERAL_PADDING_IN_DP);

        String minText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMinValue());
        String maxText = String.valueOf(getSelectedMaxValue());
        float minTextWidth = paint.measureText(minText) + offset;
        float maxTextWidth = paint.measureText(maxText) + offset;

        if (!mSingleThumb) {
            canvas.drawText(minText,
                    normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue) - minTextWidth * 0.5f,
                    mDistanceToTop + mTextSize,
                    paint);

        canvas.drawText(maxText,
                normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue) - maxTextWidth * 0.5f,
                mDistanceToTop + mTextSize,
                paint);
```

for the thumb text

Also, since you made it shorter, you'll want to set

```
public static final int HEIGHT_IN_DP = 18;
```